# Printing values of field using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I am pretty new at python scripting and I am trying to print values of a field to screen.

My code is:

```
import arcpy
layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage('Layer Name : '+layer)
feature_count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(layer).getOutput(0))
arcpy.AddMessage("{0} has {1} features.".format(layer, feature_count))
field = "SURVEYID"
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, (field))]
uniqueValues = set(values)
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(layer)]
arcpy.AddMessage(uniqueValues)
```

After running the script I am getting this result

```
set([u'S0161', u'S0160', u'S0110', u'S0111', u'S0033', u'S0032', u'S0031', u'S0030', u'S0037', u'S0036', u'S0035', u'S0034', u'S0143', u'S0142', u'S0039', u'S0038', u'S0147', u'S0146', u'S0145', u'S0144', u'S0315', u'S0169', u'S0209', u'S0154', u'S0155', u'S0156', u'S0157', u'S0150', u'S0151', u'S0152', u'S0153', u'S0168', u'S0158', u'S0159', u'S0302', u'S0028', u'S0029', u'S0024', u'S0025', u'S0026', u'S0027', u'S0020', u'S0021', u'S0022', u'S0023', u'S0314', u'S0307', u'S0109', u'S0312', u'S0108', u'S0171', u'S0310', u'S0313', u'S0121', u'S0120', u'S0123', u'S0122', u'S0125', u'S0124', u'S0127', u'S0126', u'S0129', u'S0128', u'S0311', u'S0059', u'S0058', u'S0051', u'S0050', u'S0053', u'S0052', u'S0055', u'S0054', u'S0057', u'S0056', u'S0101', u'S0100', u'S0208', u'S0149', u'S0132', u'S0133', u'S0130', u'S0131', u'S0136', u'S0137', u'S0134', u'S0135', u'S0309', u'S0138', u'S0139', u'S0118', u'S0048', u'S0049', u'S0042', u'S0043', u'S0040', u'S0041', u'S0046', u'S0047', u'S0044', u'S0045', u'S0305', u'S0304', u'S0170', u'S0141', u'S0119', u'S0306', u'S0140', u'S0301', u'S0077', u'S0076', u'S0075', u'S0074', u'S0073', u'S0303', u'S0071', u'S0070', u'S0107', u'S0106', u'S0105', u'S0104', u'S0103', u'S0102', u'S0079', u'S0078', u'S0187', u'S0186', u'S0185', u'S0184', u'S0183', u'S0182', u'S0181', u'S0180', u'S0189', u'S0188', u'S0148', u'S0060', u'S0061', u'S0062', u'S0063', u'S0064', u'S0065', u'S0066', u'S0067', u'S0068', u'S0069', u'S0112', u'S0113', u'S0114', u'S0115', u'S0116', u'S0117', u'S0190', u'S0191', u'S0192', u'S0193', u'S0194', u'S0195', u'S0196', u'S0197', u'S0198', u'S0199', u'S0179', u'S0200', u'S0201', u'S0204', u'S0205', u'S0206', u'S0207', u'S0099', u'S0098', u'S0202', u'S0203', u'S0095', u'S0094', u'S0097', u'S0096', u'S0091', u'S0090', u'S0093', u'S0092', u'S0015', u'S0014', u'S0017', u'S0016', u'S0011', u'S0010', u'S0013', u'S0012', u'S0165', u'S0164', u'S0167', u'S0166', u'S0019', u'S0018', u'S0163', u'S0162', u'S0088', u'S0089', u'S0086', u'S0087', u'S0084', u'S0085', u'S0082', u'S0083', u'S0080', u'S0081', u'S0006', u'S0007', u'S0004', u'S0005', u'S0002', u'S0003', u'S0178', u'S0001', u'S0176', u'S0177', u'S0174', u'S0175', u'S0172', u'S0173', u'S0008', u'S0009'])
```

But I am desiring to get this (below) kind of message, and I don't want to get unique values.

```
S0161
S0160
S0110
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 8):

You want to access each item in the set individually, and print it:

```
for value in uniqueValues:
    arcpy.AddMessage(value)
```